# How to gsub for matching strings and simultaneously remove non-matching strings?

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

I have a dataframe with a column of strings that I want to further label into the following categories: city, country, and continent. I used gsub to replace all the cities with "City," all the countries with "Country," and all the continents with "Continent."

```
#This is what I have
dataframe
Color     Letter     Words
red       A          Paris,Asia,parrot,Antarctica,North America,cat,lizard
blue      A          Panama,New York,Africa,dog,Tokyo,Washington DC,fish
red       B          Copenhagen,bird,USA,Japan,Chicago,Mexico,insect
blue      B          Israel,Antarctica,horse,South America,North America,turtle,Brazil

#This is what I want
dataframe
Color     Letter     New
red       A          City,Continent
blue      A          Country,City,Continent
red       B          City,Country
blue      B          Country,Continent


#This is the code I have so far
dataframe$New <- NA

#groups all the cities
dataframe$New <- lapply)dataframe$Words, function(x) {
   gsub("Paris|New York|Tokyo|Washington DC|Copenhagen|Chicago", "City", x)})

#groups all the countries
dataframe$New <- lapply)dataframe$Words, function(x) {
   gsub("Panama|USA|Japan|Mexico|Israel|Brazil", "Country", x)})

#groups all the continents
dataframe$New <- lapply)dataframe$Words, function(x) {
   gsub("Asia|Antarctica|Africa|North America|South America", "Continent", x)})

dataframe$Words <- NULL
```

How do I keep prevent overwriting in dataframe$New each time and how do I delete the extra words (i.e. fish, horse, cat)?

The above data is an example based on a very large dataset. In the dataset the Words column has many repeats. See below for some sample rows from dataframe$Words:

````
Words
Panama,Paris
Panama,Israel,cat
Panama,Paris,horse,
Panama,Asia
Panama
Panama,Chicago
Israel,Chicago
Israel,lizard,Paris
Israel,Panama,horse,Africa
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider pasting several `ifelse` calls checking for specific strings:

```
dataframe$New <- paste(ifelse(grepl("Paris|New York|Tokyo|Washington DC|Copenhagen|Chicago", dataframe$Words), "City", "N/A"), 
                       ifelse(grepl("Panama|USA|Japan|Mexico|Israel|Brazil", dataframe$Words), "Country", "N/A"),
                       ifelse(grepl("Asia|Antarctica|Africa|North America|South America", dataframe$Words), "Continent", "N/A"),
                       sep=",")

dataframe$New <- gsub("N/A,|,N/A", "", dataframe$New)

dataframe

#   Color Letter                                                             Words                    New
# 1   red      A             Paris,Asia,parrot,Antarctica,North America,cat,lizard         City,Continent
# 2  blue      A               Panama,New York,Africa,dog,Tokyo,Washington DC,fish City,Country,Continent
# 3   red      B                   Copenhagen,bird,USA,Japan,Chicago,Mexico,insect           City,Country
# 4  blue      B Israel,Antarctica,horse,South America,North America,turtle,Brazil      Country,Continent
```

Or dryer version with `do.call` + `lapply`:

```
strs <- list(c("Paris|New York|Tokyo|Washington DC|Copenhagen|Chicago", "City"),
             c("Panama|USA|Japan|Mexico|Israel|Brazil", "Country"),
             c("Asia|Antarctica|Africa|North America|South America", "Continent"))

df$New2 <- do.call(paste,
                   c(lapply(strs, function(s) ifelse(grepl(s[1], df$Words), s[2], "N/A")), 
                     list(sep=",")))
df$New2 <- gsub("N/A,|,N/A", "", df$New2)
```

Comment: This almost works but there is something off with the N/As... The ifelse needs a "no" argument for each statement but if I turn everything else in the cell to "N/A" then later ifelse statements won't work. The resulting list has a ton of "N/A" where there shouldn't be.

Comment: And what is that? As you can see it works great with your sample. I use `N/A` as placeholder to be replaced in next line.

Comment: Is there a way to make the "no" argument "do nothing" until the last ifelse statement?

Comment: Please update your post with data that yields your issues. You can use empty string `""` but your result may have empty comma enclosed spaces: (e.g., `,Country,Continent`).

Comment: dataframe$Words has many repeats so when the "no" argument is N/A in one row, the next ifelse statement cannot recognize that a string was there. I added an example above.

Comment: I do not understand. See output with this demo (https://rextester.com/TCQ26411) Please explain what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to create a key/value pair of `list` and then extract the elements after replacement by matching the 'key's

```
library(gsubfn)
# key val list
lst1 <- list(Paris = "City", `New York` = "City", Tokyo = "City", 
  `Washington DC` = "City", 
    Copenhagen = "City", Chicago = "City", Panama = "Country", 
    USA = "Country", Japan = "Country", Mexico = "Country", Israel = "Country", 
    Brazil = "Country", Asia = "Continent", Antarctica = "Continent",      
    Africa = "Continent", `North America` = "Continent", 
    `South America` = "Continent")
```

Extract the matching values with `strapply` into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `sapply` and `paste` the `unique` strings that are either 'City', 'Continent' or 'Country'

```
nm1 <- c("City", "Continent", "Country")
df1$New <- sapply(strapply(df1$Words,  "([^,]+)", lst1), function(x)  
        paste(unique(x[x %in% nm1]), collapse=","))
df1$New
#[1] "City,Continent"         "Country,City,Continent"
#[3] "City,Country"           "Country,Continent"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Color = c("red", "blue", "red", "blue"), Letter = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B"), Words = c("Paris,Asia,parrot,Antarctica,North America,cat,lizard", 
"Panama,New York,Africa,dog,Tokyo,Washington DC,fish", 
  "Copenhagen,bird,USA,Japan,Chicago,Mexico,insect", 
"Israel,Antarctica,horse,South America,North America,turtle,Brazil"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```